# error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp': No such file or directory

Tags: c++, qt

I am trying to build a project using Qt creator tool in windows but when I built it , I got this error: error: C1083: Cannot open include file: 'xercesc/util/XMLString.hpp': No such file or directory

So do I have to download this library? but i did not find it

I am using Qt in order to open a tool called netanim used for NS3 tool

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using Netanim in advanced mode, Xerces is necessary, see here https://www.nsnam.org/wiki/NetAnim_Advanced_mode

Answer (score 1):

The Xerces-c++ you can download from here: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/download.cgi

I dont know that netanim software, but I think they should include information about what type and versions of 3rd parts they are using. Without required libraries it is impossible to compile anything.